# How Can I Fade a Div's Text from Full Opacity to No Opacity (with no color)

Tags: html, css, text, gradient, fade

I'm trying to fade text with a gradient in CSS without any color involved.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do...
[image]

Here is some source code you can use to help me with my task:
https://jsfiddle.net/cwqenuy7/3/

**HTML**

```
<div id="fadedDiv">
   <p>Hello</p>
   <p>This</p>
   <p>Text</p>
   <p>Should</p>
   <p>Be</p>
   <p>Fading</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-image: url('https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/664169149002874880/z1fmxo00.jpg');
}

#fadedDiv {
   width: 140px;
   height: auto;
   border: 1px solid red;
   padding: 0 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#fadedDiv p {
   margin: 0;
}
```

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: well it would be great if you share your current code to append required code in it instead of creating a whole new page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve it use the Opacity css property:

```
<p style="opacity:1">Hello</p>
<p style="opacity:0.8">This</p>
<p style="opacity:0.6">Text</p>
<p style="opacity:0.5">Should</p>
<p style="opacity:0.4">Be</p>
<p style="opacity:0.3">Fading</p>
```

Your updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwqenuy7/4/)